# Need clarity on Vector subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Given that U is subspace of V. I need to know that if two vectors a,b are in V and (a+b) lies in U, then is it necessary that a, b both lie in U?

In other words is the check for closure property of a subspace an ‘iff’ condition ? That is
if a,b in U then a+b is also in U

Comment: Consider $V=\mathbb R^2$, $U=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$, $a=(1,1)$, and $b=(1,-1)$; $a+b\in U$ but $a,b\not\in U$

Comment: Does $x+(-x)=0$ tell you something?

Comment: (-a-b) lies in U, but still i dont get your hint. Anyway my doubt is clarified

Comment: Consider $U=\{\vec0\}$, $a=x\not\in U$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Aah, now it clicked...Trivial subspaces are not so trivial sometimes!

Comment: My thought for a counter-example was to take U= R², V= {(x, y)| x= y}, a= (1, 0), b= (0, 1).  Then a+ b= (1, 1) is in V but neither a nor b is.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey:  I think you switched $U$ and $V$ — $U$ is supposed to be a subspace of $V$ — but otherwise your example is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of axioms, there is no "iff." The axiom is "If $a,b \in U,$then $a+b \in U$." In terms of properties, note that if $a+b \in U$ then either both $a$ and $b$ belong to $U$ or neither $a$ nor $b$ belongs to $U$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification